# How to add "^" as an argument to a command in emac's eshell?

Tags: emacs, special-characters, eshell

I am trying to make a command-line calculator for use by a webpage I am making. But when I try to execute in eshell with `java Calculate -exp 10^20^30`
I get:

```
:s/20/30/
Wrong type argument: stringp, 106
```

But that same command works fine in the regular PuTTY terminal, wrapping quotations around 10^20^30 didn't work and neither did using 10\^20\^30. I can execute bash commands but found it convenient to use eshell because I can copy and paste easily from eshell within PuTTY.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Just realized that I could also run the command with no issue using `M-x shell` but still want to know how to put special characters in eshell if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to assign `^` to a variable in the following way

```
setq x $(string 94)
```

You can then try

```
java Calculate -exp 10"$x"20"$x"30
```

Or use it directly

```
java Calculate -exp 10$(string 94)20$(string 94)30
```